# Error when creating a raster brick in a loop

Tags: r, loops, for-loop, stack, raster

I am working with time series of rasters and I need to analyse a ts of 17 dates. For each date, I imported band 5 and band 7. I made a list of the 17 bands-5 and a list of the 17 bands-7, called respectively list_B5 and list_B7.
I would like to stack together bands of the same date, so: the first raster of list_B5 with the first raster of list_B7; the second raster of list_B5 with the second raster of list_B7; and so on.

I am new to loops, but I tried to write one:

```
    for (i in seq_along(length(list_B5)) [1]) {
      for (j in seq_along(length(list_B7)) [2]) {
        B5 <- raster(list_B5[[i]]) #extract the raster of interest
        B7 <- raster(list_B7[[j]]) #extract the raster of interest
        test[i,j] <- brick(B5, B7) #stack them together
      }
    }
```

with "test" being:

```
test <- brick(nrows=5490, ncol=5490, nl=17)
```

Unfortunately I get the following error:

```
Error in (function (classes, fdef, mtable)  : 
unable to find an inherited method for function ‘raster’ for signature ‘"NULL"’
```

I do not understand why it doesn't accept the lines in which I try to extract the raster of interest, since this line alone usually works:

```
> raster(list_B5[[3]])
class       : RasterLayer 
dimensions  : 5490, 5490, 30140100  (nrow, ncol, ncell)
resolution  : 20, 20  (x, y)
extent      : 6e+05, 709800, 5590200, 5700000  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
coord. ref. : +proj=utm +zone=31 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0
```

Can someone explain to me why I get the above mentioned error?

Comment: If you want to stack B5 and B7 from the same date, why do you use `i` and `j`? Also, why do you use `i` with `[1]` and `j` with `[2]`? I recommend you detele `j` loop and use only `i`. If `test` is a list, use `test[[i]] <- brick(B5, B7)`

Answer (score 1):

#### Why your code is broken

`seq_along(length(list_B5))` is not doing what you expect it to. Rather, it just returns `1`. You would need to use either `seq_along(list_B5)`, or `seq_len(length(list_B5))`. Take a look at the docs for info.

Later, you subset `1` to its second element: `seq_along(length(list_B7))[2]`. This introduces an `NA`, which causes problems later on.

You can debug these issues on your own, by testing parts of your code to see if they produce the expected result. E.g., run `seq_along(length(list_B5))[1]` and `seq_along(length(list_B7))[2]` and see if they generate the sequences you hoped for.

---

#### A simpler way

It's probably easiest to do this with `mapply`.

```
list_b5 <- replicate(17, raster(matrix(runif(12), ncol=3)))
list_b7 <- replicate(17, raster(matrix(runif(12), ncol=3)))

mapply(stack, list_b5, list_b7)
```

Here, `mapply` loops over elements of `list_b5` and `list_b7` simultaneously, and applies the `stack` function (replace with `brick` if you prefer).

If your lists are actually file paths, then you can do:

```
list_b5 <- replicate(17, raster(matrix(runif(12), ncol=3)))
list_b7 <- replicate(17, raster(matrix(runif(12), ncol=3)))

mapply(function(x, y) stack(raster(x), raster(y)), list_b5, list_b7)
```

---

#### To fix your approach

And here's how you'd do it with a `for` loop:

```
test <- list(length=17)
for (i in seq_along(list_b5)) {
    b5 <- list_b5[[i]]
    b7 <- list_b7[[i]]
    test[[i]] <- stack(b5, b7)
}
```

or if your lists are file paths,

```
test <- list(length=17)
for (i in seq_along(list_b5)) {
    b5 <- raster(list_b5[[i]])
    b7 <- raster(list_b7[[i]])
    test[[i]] <- stack(b5, b7)
}
```